# jspuseBean class property not valid

Tags: java, jsp

I am trying to handle the login form data using the loginhandler jsp. It is throwing an exception /LoginHandler.jsp (line: 11, column: 0) The value for the useBean class attribute beans.UserDetails is invalid.

```
<%
    String username = handler.getUsername();
    String password = handler.getPassword();

    try {
        if (username.equals("nvnmandadhi") && password.equals("Naveen")) {

            response.sendRedirect("hello.jsp");
        } else {

            response.sendRedirect("Login.jsp");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        response.sendRedirect("error.jsp");
    }
%>
```

Comment: <jsp:useBean id="handler" class="beans.UserDetails" scope="request"></jsp:useBean>
<jsp:setProperty property="*" name="handler" />
 
 <%
  String username = handler.getUsername();
  String password = handler.getPassword();

  try {
   if (username.equals("nvnmandadhi") && password.equals("Naveen")) {

    response.sendRedirect("hello.jsp");
   } else {

    response.sendRedirect("Login.jsp");
   }

  } catch (Exception e) {
   response.sendRedirect("error.jsp");
  }
 %>

Comment: Do your package name starts with beans ? class should have the value of fully qualified class name

Comment: I figured it out, thanks! I din't have a default constructor in my Bean. That was the problem!